# Functions using any domain and range

Tags: functions

a function $f(x)$ has domain $[-3,2] \cup (5,\infty)$ and. range $(0,4) \cup (4,\infty)$ i need to find the function .
I wanted to know how can i find it without knowing what domain number gives which range number ?

Comment: There are many functions, not just one, which have that domain and that range.

Comment: Yes then how would we know about which fumction is talked in a question and how would we find it

Comment: You can’t. But are you sure that’s exactly what your question says?

Comment: Is the function assumed to be linear or quadratic or exponential, and are you given any specific values of the function, such as $f(1) = 14?$ My guess is that you are omitting something provided in the instructions.

Comment: Basically i need to sketch a graph and for that i need the function

Comment: You need *a* function or you need *the* function?

Comment: Nothing is given about its being linear or quadratic .just its aked to sktch a graph

Comment: A function is given

Comment: If you want to draw **a** function with the desired domain and codomain (*emphasis on the fact that there are infinitely many such functions*)... then place your pen or pencil on paper, and run the tip of your drawing instrument along the paper to make a mark.  More specifically, do it on graph paper or a paper with axes drawn and labeled such that the only marks you draw have x-coordinates between $-3$ and $2$ or between $5$ and extending to the far right edge of the paper.  Further, make sure that the only marks you draw have y-coordinates in their desired range.

Comment: Finally, make sure that for each $x$-coordinate in your desired domain that exactly one point is drawn, that it passes the "*horizontal line test*".  Otherwise... if you want to draw zig-zags, if you want to lift your pencil and jump up, if you want it to be squiggly, curvey, straight... that is entirely up to you.  Whatever decisions you make just influence what the exact function it was that you happened to draw is.

Comment: Ahh. Now it’s asked to sketch *a* graph. Which, like I originally commented, suggests there are *many* possible functions you could draw, but the function would have to be defined piecewise. One is: $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-5} + 4$ for $x> 5$, and $f(x) = -\frac{4}{5}x + \frac{8}{5}$ for $x \in (-3,2)$, and $f(-3) = f(2) = 1$.

Comment: Now... as for crafting a convenient function before drawing it... you should be familiar with the usual building blocks and how to compose them or use them in piecewise defined functions, etc... and how to manipulate them in order to have desired domains or ranges.  Examples of building blocks of functions that you are expected to know would be things like lines $ax+b$ and reciprocals $\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Okay now i understand .thanku 